# tinymce модификация плагина image

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Как можно модифицировать плагин вставки изображений, что бы при добавлении картинки, он задавал размеры указанные мной и при этом оборачивал в тег `<a>`? Хочу просто подключить lightbox...

Comment: в тег a... и задавал размеры по умолчанию, не давай возможность сделать это пользователю.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Приведите ваш код. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: В tinymce есть встроенный плагин для добавления картинок в сообщение. Работает по принципу что просто вставляет картинку с тегом <img> и размерами (их он то же предлагает указать. Мне необходимо сделать, что бы данный плагин по такому принципу: мы вставляем картинку, он оборачивает её в <a href="ссыль" data="lightbox"><img src="ссыль" width и height жёстко заданны мной> вот как то так.